# What android folders should be backed up?

Tags: android, eclipse, git

I've recently started to back up my whole project's folder in my workspace via Git. However, I've noticed that there are files that keep getting generated by Eclipse. I think that these files including their parent directories don't need to be backed up. What folders need to be backed up in an Android project?

Answer (score 2):

Only `gen` and `bin` are auto-generated, so anything else should be backed up.

As @CommonsWare pointed out, if you are using the new Gradle-based build system, `build` is also auto-generated, so needn't be backed up.

Comment: `build/` is also auto-generated, if you are using the new Gradle-based build system (which includes Android Studio).

Comment: Correct, but this was tagged with `Eclipse`, so I referred to the old build system.

Comment: Good point (I missed that), but since others might miss that tag too, I figure it's worth mentioning.